# Order of Feature Encoding, Feature Selection and normalization

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, feature-selection

I am trying to use a neural network for binary and multi-class classification. My dataset has binary, numeric and nominal variables. The nominal values on training set has a lot of values, so when I perform `OneHotEncoding` the dimension moves from `42` to `122`. Also some of the values are only present on training set because the dataset was proposed this way.

So I used the following order:

1. One-hot encoding
2. Normalization
3. Feature Selection or PCA

But I found some people, who also used neural networks, performed feature selection before even performing One-hot Encoding. Which is strange for me because neural network only work numerical data. So running a feature selection algorithm that might *delete* the categorical values could be harming to the neural network, especially that one hot encoding has an impact on the dimensional of the whole model.

But I don't know, so I have to ask: What is the correct order here? This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46062679/right-order-of-doing-feature-selection-pca-and-normalization) follows the order I used, but I am more interested about the one-hot encoding and feature selection part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

qu: What is the correct order here?
This order may vary based on your application and data.

For example in your qu as why feature selection used before oneHotEncoding, it is applicable in your nominal data which you state that:
 "The nominal values on training set has a lot of values, so when I perform OneHotEncoding the dimension moves from 42 to 122"
In this application it is useful to do feature selection before oneHotEncoding.

- "So running a feature selection algorithm that might delete the categorical values could be harming to the neural network, especially that one hot encoding has an impact on the dimensional of the whole model" -> your interpretation of the neural network in this way is not correct at all, because the existence of useless categorical values to one hot encoding may make the tuning of neural network hard (or result in no convergence on neural network tuning) or computational complexity.